# Angular 8 get data attributes

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I created this example code in angular 8. The button has two data attributes, but I only see one attribute. 
Is this a syntax error or a bug?

```
 <button [attr.data-popolamento]="all" [attr.data-id]="1" (click)="ricercaAnagrafica($event)" class=" btn btn-sm btn-elevate btn-success"><i class="la la-search"></i>Ricerca Anagrafica</button>
```

[Angular screen of target in console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oW0B3.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that `all` is not declared. Since you are using `[attr.data-popolamento]` it will be not defined as a simple string. If you try it with `[attr.data-popolamento]="100"`, it will work, since "100" is not a string. If you would like to pass a simple string, I would recommend using the simple HTML `data-data-popolamento="all"`. Or you could also define your **variable** `all` and then using it the same way.

Answer (score 0):

When you bind a property, the expression is needed.

```
[property]="expression"
```

So if you want to bind a `all` string to `data-popolamento` attribute, you should do like below:

```
[attr.data-popolamento]="'all'"
```

Edited snippet:

```
<button [attr.data-popolamento]="'all'" [attr.data-id]="1" (click)="ricercaAnagrafica($event)" class=" btn btn-sm btn-elevate btn-success">
  <i class="la la-search"></i>Ricerca Anagrafica
</button>
```